# Apache Camel - recipientList - need of end

Tags: apache-camel

After using `recipientList` in a camel route, within a `choice.when`, I would like to route this further to another destination with `to("xy")`.

Syntax-highlighting in a java IDE is showing me that this is not possible.

If I put an `end` after `recipientList`, all appears to fit again.

Is that required? I could not find any examples in the docs/net showing s/t similar...

```
.choice()
   .when(aPredicate)
      .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME).simple("st")
      .recipientList(getAValueBuilder())
      .end()
      .to("ftp:me@ftpserv//usr/dest")
   .when(anotherPredicate)
      .to(nirv)
      .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME).simple("nt")
      .to("ftp:me@ftpserv//usr/anotherdest")
.end()
```

Generarilly I am not sure, while using `choice`, when to use `end`. And to make it more difficult, there is an `endChoice`...

I tryed to use the formatting, to show the way I think it should be use above.

Thanks for feedback.

Comment: I'm assuming you've already read [this FAQ](http://camel.apache.org/why-can-i-not-use-when-or-otherwise-in-a-java-camel-route.html) and tried the suggestions?

Comment: In plain english: endChoice does end a branch within the choice? If yes the name is a bit confusing. I guess is not easy to find a name which fits 100% to the functionality...

Comment: Camel Java DSL has a bunch of `endThis`. They exist due to limitations of using Java as DSL in rare cases and are not required most of the time. In reality they are not "end This", but rather a short version of "end and return to This". The naming is a bit unfortunate, indeed.